# Send sensor data over internet to a server

Tags: sensors, communication, aws-iot, wireless, data-transfer

I had a project planned on monitoring sensors. I wanted to read sensor data
over the internet. How should I proceed with the setup?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Hi @Some_dude, I don't think we can give you a specific answer without some more details. What type of sensor do you have (device links are great)? What device are you going to use to read the data you receive? Be sure to [edit] and add all this.

Comment: You need to sign in with the same account to be able to edit your own posts.

Answer (score 3):

1. You need to have a dedicated server that collects data from all sensors (say, s1, s2, s3). The server can be a Raspberry Pi or a PC running your server program (say IP=192.168.0.10) and listening on port (say, 7777)
2. Code http endpoints on your server program which will read data from the requested sensor (say, http://public-ip:7777/sensors/s1/data)
3. Enable port forwarding on your wifi router to forward requests to the port 7777 to your server's internal IP (192.168.0.10)
4. Find your router's external IP and access the data using above mentioned URL
5. If this is done, you can enable https for the server to secure your data

Answer (score 3):

1. You can use Node MCU ESP8266 as a better option than arduino as it has inbuilt wifi and bluetooth access. And yes of course Raspberrypi is also an another SBC with inbuilt Wifi which cost 2700 rs around way higher than ESP8266.
2. And also more over in Node MCU ESP8266 you have inbuilt battery version as well, which makes your project more feasible.
3. Also another option would be working GSM modules (along with arduino) as it will remove the dependenecy on any other internet network.

Cheers for the Maker in you...

Answer (score 2):

You can use an Arduino to send the data of that sensor to a web service. That web service can allow you to read or connect with the sensor from any place.

You can use ThingSpeak or other similar, or your own web service.

Another option is to connect that sensor to a Raspberry Pi (RPi) and create in the RPi a web service.